# ESP32 EXT1 wakeup

Tags: arduino, sleep, esp32

I have an ESP32 dev kit connected to a 3 x 4 matrix keypad.

3 columns are connected to the PINS: 12, 13, 27

4 rows are connected to the PINS: 14, 15, 32, 33

GOAL: I would love to be able to put the MCU in deep sleep mode and be able to wake it up with a keypress, meaning ANY keypress, not one specifically.

I've put together this piece of code

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Wait for serial.
  while (!Serial)
    delay(100);
  Serial.println("I am ON");
  // power all columns.
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(27, OUTPUT);
  // enable all rows as input (HIGH).
  pinMode(14, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
  pinMode(15, INPUT_PULLDOWN); // tried also pin 35, no luck.
  pinMode(32, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
  pinMode(33, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
  esp_sleep_enable_ext1_wakeup(0b001100000000000000001100000000000000, ESP_EXT1_WAKEUP_ANY_HIGH);
  // hold the pin HIGH during sleep.
  gpio_deep_sleep_hold_en();

  // do the actual output on the pins.
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(27, HIGH);

  // delay to make sure.
  delay(500);
  esp_deep_sleep_start();
}
```

The problem seems that the whole setup is erratic. Some keypresses work more consistently than others. But more consistently still means that sometime the more consistent key, won't be able to wake up the device.

I've tried the snippet with 2 different boards (Huzzah32 and a generic dev kit) with the same results.

The keypad setup works otherwise great, meaning I am able to read the keypresses reliably.

Comment: Am I correct that this keyboard matrix is the kind of setup that uses a network of resistors so that each keypress generates a unique voltage that identifies the key being pressed? If that's the case, it's likely that the voltages for some of the keys are not within the threshold needed for generating an interrupt. You'd do better asking on the Arduino Stack Overflow as that one takes hardware questions.

Comment: No, a matrix keypad connects columns pins to row pins. In order to read a keypress, voltage must be applied to column pins one at the time and read from rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found it: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/sleep_modes.html#external-wakeup-ext1
The pull-up/down resistors are not normally enabled during deep sleep, which seems to explain the inconsistencies.